# Mobile menu links not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an issue with a mobile drop down menu where the links within the menu do not trigger and it just send the div back to hiding without going to page.

```
<div id="nav-mobile">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://www.solostream.com/wp-content/themes/solostream/img/dropdown-menu-white.png" /></a>
    <ul style="display: none;">
        <li><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Memberships</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Platinum Membership</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Equipment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Video Production</a></li>
        <li id="last-child"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>


<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#nav-mobile ul').hide();
    $('#nav-mobile').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#nav-mobile ul').slideToggle();
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: So when you click `Home` it does nothing?

Comment: I fixed it, It was the prevent default that was causing the problem. My bad! Doh!

Answer (score 0):

revome the e.preventDefault()

```
$('#nav-mobile').click(function(e) {
     //e.preventDefault();
     $('#nav-mobile ul').slideToggle();
});
```

look here to see the emulation: http://jsfiddle.net/m9bug6tk/2/